# Terminal Emulator - compare contrast KERMIT and Reflection by attachmate?

Tags: reflection, terminal-emulator, kermit

Can someone compare and contrast Reflection and KERMIT?  Do they do the same thing?  Which is better?  Why?  We may need to use one of these at my business and we are looking for input.

Thanks

W

Answer (score 1):

They both do terminal emulation.  Assuming they both emulate the terminals you need, they would be roughly equivalent.

Reflection is a great terminal emulator that I have used in various environments since the early 1980s.  It is commercially supported by a company that has been in business for many years. I would highly recommend it over Kermit in commercial settings.